# cvWatershed unsupported format or combination of formats

Tags: c, opencv, codeblocks, watershed

I'm working with OpenCV 2.4.11 in C on Code::Blocks, in particular through the O'Reilly book Learning OpenCV. The section on the watershed algorithm was a bit short, so I thought I'd play with it a bit to see how exactly it works. However, every time I call the function I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Only 32-bit, 1-chann
>   el output images are supported) in cvWatershed

My program so far is very simple:

```
int main(int arg, int arg2) {
//open windows
cvNamedWindow("Input", 1 );
cvNamedWindow("Markings", 1 );

//load images
IplImage* input = cvLoadImage("ActualDoorPhoto.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
assert(input != NULL);

IplImage* markingstemp = cvLoadImage("ActualMarkingTest.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
assert(markingstemp != NULL);

//prepare markings
IplImage* markings = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(markingstemp), 32, 1);
CvMat* markmat = cvCreateMat(input->width, input->height, CV_32FC1);

cvWatershed(input, markmat);

cvShowImage("Input", input);
cvShowImage("Markings", markings);
cvWaitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

I have tried putting both markings and markmat as the second argument for cvWatershed, as well as several other things (notably markings with the contours of markingstemp drawn onto it), but every time I get the same error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I've tried that and the error has changed to "OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The input and output images
must have the same size) in cvWatershed"
This seems odd since one's size is drawn from the other. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: You're inverting dimensions: `CvMat* markmat = cvCreateMat(input->height, input->width, CV_32FC1);` Probably format should be `CV_32SC1` also.

Comment: Oh, darn, yeah, that worked. Thanks! Seems like a silly question now.

Comment: Is there any way to remove this question or should I just add an answer when I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inverting the dimensions of the output matrix. It should be:

```
CvMat* markmat = cvCreateMat(input->height, input->width, CV_32FC1);
```

The format should also probably be changed to `CV_32SC1`.